# Git processes left active after devops-agent build

Tags: windows, git, azure-devops

We recently switched from an onprem TFS server to using Azure Devops to compile and build our solution.

In Azure devops we have a git repo with code, and a CI pipeline to build the development-branch.
This works as it should.

We also have two agents running on an onprem windows server with 2 virtual cores and plenty of ram and diskspace.

But we are also having problems with our agents, in that they will leave git-processes alive after they have completed, which again sometimes locks certain files.

After a couple of days running the agents, several processes are still alive, resulting in
[image: After a couple of days running the agents]

errors when trying to do a git-clean
[image: will result errors when trying run git-clean]

The following is our build-pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master
pool:
    name: 'ONPREM'
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: /m /r /p:Configuration=$(buildConfiguration));UseEnv=true;BuildInParallel=true 
/nr:false /nologo
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Any feedback and assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you use Process Explorer to see what arguments these got invoked with? Can you check the agents logs to see whether it mentions issues killing these processes? Do you have any pre-receive hooks etc that may depend on the credentials being present?

Comment: Ok, so I did a little digging.
All of the processes  were invoked by calling 'git.exe clean -ffdx'. I would also see signs of struggle when I was trying to close the processes, but it does report success in the end.

Comment: I copied most of the logfile here: https://controlc.com/10507da5... With 60 minutes timeout it's easy to see where the agent gave up at line #315

Comment: My guess would be the anti-virus is causing issues. You'll probably need to us something like ProcMon to know what is holding on the lock causing the delete to fail.

Comment: A runaway unit test can also be the cause. Or a still running webserver.

Comment: Appreciate the input Jesse, and you might be right. There is an antivirus running on the server, but the agentX folders should be ignored. Still the best clue to work with. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this will help you find the culprit: https://superuser.com/a/1203347/132408

Comment: When you config the agent, are you using the admin access level to open the PowerShell? Do you have any fire wall in your agent machine/network, sometime the fire wall role will block some service connection from azure devops service to your agent. If it is possible, can you try to create a new self-agent in other machine, just for check if you still have this issue. And maybe you can create a ps script to help you clean these git process.